# Ubuntu Connect Button Disabled, cannot connect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm trying to connect to my school network from Ubuntu 12. The network is WPA encrypted and I can connect just fine if the network manager establishes a connection automatically.  However, when I get disconnected and try to reconnect a username and password prompt pops up.  The credentials are already stored and are autofilled in correctly, but the Connect button is disabled so I can't actually connect to the network.

What can I do? The only guess I've found so far is the password is [too short and Ubuntu is expecting a full WPA key](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=952173). I don't administer the school network though so I certainly can't change that.

Comment: If you're connecting with username and password, then it's radius-based WPA-eap, so there is no wpa key.

Comment: Just want to confirm that you can connect to other wifi network. Also please add output if "iwconfig".

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a minimum password length issue as you stated. The funny thing is that when the connection is made automatically, Ubuntu doesn't seem to complain. It's only when a connection is attempted through the GUI that the problem occurs.

You could try to restart networking...

Either...

> sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

or...

> sudo service networking restart

Or... you could try using a script to get a connection...

```
#! /bin/bash
ifconfig wlan0
iwconfig wlan0 essid [NETWORK_ID] [key WIRELESS_KEY]
dhclient wlan0
```

This assumes your interface is called `wlan0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to restart the Ubuntu network manager applet:

```
killall nm-applet; nm-applet
```